# I can not make support multilanguage for all API

Tags: java, android, localization

my logcat shows `9/com.fishexpert E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaaacb680`

I have tried those code for multilanguage. But unfortunately, it is not supporting below 23 API but fine for API 24 to 29

```java
     @SuppressWarnings(value = "deprication")
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
        public void setLocale(String localeName) {
            if (!localeName.equals(currentLanguage)) {
                myLocale = new Locale(localeName);
                Resources res = getResources();
                DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
                Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    conf.setLocale(myLocale);
                    res.updateConfiguration(conf, res.getDisplayMetrics());

                    Intent refresh = new Intent(Language_act.this,StartingActivity.class);
                    refresh.putExtra(currentLang, localeName);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(refresh);
                }

                else{
                    conf.locale = myLocale;
                    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);

                    Intent refresh = new Intent(Language_act.this,StartingActivity.class);
                    refresh.putExtra(currentLang, localeName);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(refresh);
                }



            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Language_act.this, "Language already selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        public void onBackPressed() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }
```